# implements with different data type

Tags: java

I have 2 class just call it "Stuff" and "Customer", the classes based on my database table (JDBC) and have abstract class because this 2 classes has same few property(Id,Name), my abstract class containing(Id,Name, along with setter and getter from Id and Name variable).

I was creating 2 more class ("ExecuteStuff" and "ExecuteCustomer") which has a goal to execute a query for manipulate a data in my database,because this situation "ExecuteStuff and ExecuteCustomer" class should have method insert, update,delete and show for manipulate and showing a data from my database, because "ExecuteStuff" and "ExecuteCustomer" need a same method for process a data from my database , I decided to creating my own interface called "myData" which is contain 4 mehod (insertData(), updateData(),deleteData() and showData()) for class "ExecuteStuff" and class "ExecuteCustomer".

My problem is, what type data should I use for parameter inside a method in my interface "myData", for example = **public int insertData(Stuff stuff);** this method will work for "ExecuteStuff" but not for "ExecuteCustomer" because "ExecuteStuff" and "ExecuteCustomer" has a different object type.

Or a graceful way to solve this problem.

Comment: Am I understanding you right that `Stuff` and `Customer` implement the interface `myData`? Would you be calling `insertData()` on a `Customer` instance to insert that customer into the DB? If so, why does `insertData()` need an argument at all?

Comment: Sounds like you should just be using JPA or Spring Data.

Comment: @Michelle I already update my question. why I need an argument? because I accessing data through "Stuff" class for "ExecuteStuff" and "Customer" for "ExecuteCustomer". Class "Stuff" and "Customer" make me easy for produce data that must have mixture with another property like for example  = getTotalPrice() which is can be obtained with multiply getPrice and getValue().

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use a generic type in your interface. That way it won't matter what the data type of the parameter you pass in is.

Here is a link that explains generics:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Another solution is to use:

```
public int insertData(Object obj);
```

Since both Stuff and Customer are objects.

Hope I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generic parameter:

```
interface MyData {

public <T> T insertData(T data);
}
```

Class example:

```
class MyCustomClassThat implements MyData{
    @Override
    public <T> T insertData(T data) {

        return data;
    }
}
```

This makes the insertData method accept any class. Then you can operate on it however you like. Finally, we return the object originally presented; just in case you operated on the data object itself.